# issue Find command Linux

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a folder  and I want count all regular files in it, and for this I use this bash command:

```
find pathfolder -type f  2> err.txt | wc -l
```

In the folder there are 3 empty text files and a subfolder with inside it other text files. 
For this reason I should get 3 as a result, but I get 6 and I don't understand why. Maybe there is some options that I did not set.

If I remove the subfolder I get 4 as result

Comment: Please give us the output from `find pathfolder -type f`

Comment: Dropping the `| wc -l` should be enlightening...

Comment: There might be a hidden file which you won't be aware of.

Comment: "find pathfolder -type f" from it I get :                                               a/.DS_Store
a/1.txt
a/2.txt
a/3.txt
a/subfolder/900.txt

Comment: "a" is the folder from starts find

Comment: That is a list of 5 items (not 4 or 6!)

Comment: I want get only file 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt while I get also the ds_store and the file in the subfolder

Comment: Just use `ls | wc -l`

Comment: but I don't get the subfolder

Answer (score 2):

To grab all the files and directories in current directory without dot files:

```
shopt -u dotglob
all=(*)
```

To grab only directories:

```
dirs=(*/)
```

To count **only non-dot files** in current directory:

```
echo $(( ${#all[@]} - ${#dirs[@]} ))
```

---

To do this with `find` use:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -exec printf '%.0s.\n' {} + | wc -l
```

Comment: `-printf '.\n'` is going to be much more efficient than that `-exec`.

Comment: Yes I agree, but unfortunately `-printf` isn't available for me on OSX.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered if that was non-portable. I assume you don't have `-exec +` there either?

Comment: No, but should as `-exec printf '%.0s.\n' +`.

Comment: `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -exec printf '%.0s.\n' +` gives me this error: `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`

Comment: Oh, oops, try `-exec printf '%.0s.\n' {} +`.

Answer (score 1):

*Below solutions ignore the filenames starting with dot.*

To count the files in `pathfolder` only:

```
find pathfolder -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | wc -l
```

To count the files in ALL child directories of `pathfolder`:

```
find pathfolder -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | wc -l
```

<sup>**UPDATE: Converting comments into an answer**</sup>

Based on the suggestions received from [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava), by creating a dummy file using the command `touch $'foo\nbar'`, the `wc -l` counts this filename *twice*, like in below example:

```
$> touch $'foo\nbar'
$> find . -type f
./foo?bar
$> find . -type f | wc -l
2
```

To avoid this, get rid of the newlines before calling `wc` (anubhava's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30788454/2381750)):

```
$> find . -type f -exec printf '%.0sbla\n' {} +
bla
$> find . -type f -exec printf '%.0sbla\n' {} + | wc -l
1
```

or avoid calling `wc` at all:

```
$> find . -type f -exec sh -c 'i=0; for f; do ((i++)); done; echo $i' sh {} +
1
```

Comment: This will give wrong count if a filename has newline character

Comment: anubhava: Honestly, I never saw such filenames :) @mario-razzu: to count in ALL child directories of `pathfolder` you could use: `find pathfolder -type f -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -not -path '*/\.*'`. To cound only in `pathfolder`: `find pathfolder -type f -maxdepth 1 -not -path '*/\.*'`

Comment: I get only the files in the subfolder

Comment: @chatraed: Filenames with space and newlines are not very common but very much possible.

Comment: @anubhava: you suggest there could be a space or \n between the slash and the dot and the `-not path` pattern `'*/\.*` is not good?

Comment: No but if a filename has newline then `wc -l` will count that file as 2 instead of 1

Comment: @anubhava: created some files containing spaces and `\n` and observed no difference in the counting results. Anyways, I vote for your answer.

Comment: Thanks. In an empty directory create a file using `touch $'foo\nbar'` command and then run your first `find` command. It will print `2` instead of `1`.

Comment: Ok it works. I edited it in this way: I use only mindepth 1 and in this way find command search in all subfolder and in the main folder. The only thing not clear to me is "-not -path '*/\.*' ".

Comment: @mario razzu: You can use `-not -path '*/\.*'` or `! -name '.*'` (anubhava's version). It's the same thing to ignore the filenames starting with dot.

Comment: ok amazing! I tried to remove that(for testing) and it counts only ".DS_Store" file and not the "." and "..". is it special file?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865957/are-the-dot-and-dot-dot-files-in-unix-and-linux-real-files) .